# Tags for Springer-Verlag classes

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

A user introduced a tag [svmult](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svmult) in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68389/11002). I thought it's too specialized and changed it into broader [sv-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sv-classes).

Then I found that there exist [svjour3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svjour3) for one of their classes.

I think that since we do not need multiple [sv-foo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sv-foo) tags, the tag [svjour3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svjour3) should be a synonym of the broader [sv-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sv-classes). However, I don't have the priviledge to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agreed: actioned, merge performed, *etc.*