# Should [springer] and [springernature] be synonyms of [sv-classes]?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

We currently have the tags [springer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/springer), [springernature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/springernature), [sv-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sv-classes). The last one is the more widely used tag, with over 130 questions currently. The other two have only around 10 questions each.

Should we synonymize and merge the two smaller tags into [sv-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sv-classes)?
I'm not sure that there is a need to disambiguate the questions about the class files of Springer-Verlag and Springer Nature, even if they are technically different publishers...

---

Related: [Tags for Springer-Verlag classes](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2699/244085), though that was discussed over 9 years ago.

Comment: Upon further thought, in case we decide to keep a single tag for all Springer-related classes, then the tag [springer] might be more ideal to have as the master tag rather than [sv-classes].

Answer (score 1):

**Proposal**: Keep [springer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/springer) as the master tag, and make [springernature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/springernature) and [sv-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sv-classes) as its synonyms.

Comment: I can see merging sv-classes with springer (as an alias or simply delete one and re-tag  as the other)  but springernature is specifically for Nature, not other Springer book and Journal classes.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I would be on board with that as well.